# google.script.host.close is not a function, how to work around that?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script

I'm working on a **gmail** addon, and I want to make a popup that close itself automaticaly. Depending on the web page you look, some people say that you should do `window.top.close()`, others `google.script.host.close()`.

But here is the issue, both of them doesn't work.

- `google.script.host.close()` return that it is not a function, and looking in the google object, their is no function close so far.
- `window.top.close()` doesn't work too, because in 2021, google chrome prevent pages from iframe to do top navigation if we don't give them some attributes to allow them, which google does not do for the popups (why, google, why? You make it not working, at least allow users app to do it).

I didn't find a solution on the web, seem's like nobody have this issues, and so here I am to ask what can I do to work around it, and still have my popup close themself?

EDIT:
As it as been asked, here is a sample of the code I made:

```
function authCallback(request){
  const authorized = getOAuthService().handleCallback(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(request)))
  
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<base target='_top'>
  <body>
  <p style="font-size:24px">Success</p>
  <p>This popup should close in 5 second</p>
  <script>setTimeout(()=>{google.script.host.close()},5000)</script>
  </body>`)
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
}
```

This code is used after the user click on a button making a callback from google. when the callback is done, the callback popup is redirected to a page using this code, and so I return this html output. Everything work except for the autoclosing

Comment: gooogle .script.host.close() only works on dialogs

Comment: @Cooper ok, do you know how I should make it work then?

Comment: With gmail addons I've never had any interest because they kind of work  automatically when selecting and deselecting emails.  So I'd move on

Comment: What kind of `popup` are you talking about? Please consider providing sample code to clarify this.

Comment: How are you opening the popup? Where's the button? From a Gmail add-on card? Consider providing the related code.